# Print out values from text file to text area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

so my first attempt at asking the question was idiotic - I do apologise

So I am reading the contents of a text file - which is just rows of numbers. I am trying to calculate the sum of each row and print the answer out individually in descending order.

Here is the code in my controller :

```
 public void ReadFromText()
    {
        Array LogFileData = null;

        var logFileNameWithPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Docs/Q1InputFile.txt");

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(logFileNameWithPath))
        {
            LogFileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(logFileNameWithPath);

            foreach (var line in LogFileData)
            {
                //code goes here
            }
        }


        ViewBag.logFileContent = LogFileData;


    }
```

I am struggling to send the content from the text file to the text area and with the for each in order to calculate the sum of each row.

Here is the code for the view :

```
<h2>Question1</h2>

<div class="jumbotron">    
<p class="lead">Please click the button to load the results</p>    
<input type="button" title="LoadAnswer" value="Click me" id ="btn_run") 
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ReadFromText", "Question1")'" />   
@if (ViewBag.logFileContent != null) 
{
foreach (string dataLine in ViewBag.logFileContent) 
{
    @dataLine
    <br /> 
    } 
  }   
</div>

@Html.TextArea("ReadFromText", "Question1")

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "Index", "Home")
</div>
```

Sorry this a basic question - but I new and trying to learn from this 
Please advise

Comment: Not wanting to be mean, but it seems like a very difficult question to answer. The onclick just is javascript to change the entire page. Is that what you want? And you also have a Question1 Controller...and separate files for each question?

Comment: have you tried a simple google search on how to read values from a textfile.. there are literally several different ways to do this.. it's not that difficult..

Comment: I would design this as `public ActionResult ReadFromText(int questionID)` in a "QuestionsController" file, rather than having a separate controller for each question. Then you can easily add more questions without having to update your code. Plus you'll almost certainly have less duplication of code. Also maybe consider using a database rather than text files to store the data - much easier to maintain and more flexible. There are plenty of free database engines that you can install and use easily, and lots of tutorials on how to connect your application to them.

Comment: I have an assignment with 5 Questions - each completely separate from the other - which is why I would like to give them each a separate controller

Comment: @WillemFölscher I would not create a controller for each question == "smelly code". As ADyson has already suggested, one controller with a param will do perfectly. I can imagine you'll have a lot of repetitive code unless your abstracting the processing.

Comment: @WillemFolscher So these are homework assignment questions, with completely different inputs and outputs? That's different then. The way you described it sounded like maybe you were making a quiz application and wanted to make a separate controller for each quiz question, which would be hugely inefficient since they're all basically the same. If each homework question has totally different parameters, layout, goals etc then it makes more sense to do them separately.

Comment: @ADyson - yes - again, I'm sorry - the way I asked it was very vague, these are all different questions with different in / outputs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your button is html and in browser on client side and file is residing on server in your solution directory (not on client side)

I would do following

1. When a button in browser is pressed I will fire an ajax call to server.
2. On server controller would open a file stream to this file and read lines one by one or whatever way you want to do with them and get the output sent out in json format.
3. When server returns output to ajax response i will replace the text area with that response or append it if needed.

All these three steps can be done individually with test data. I would first create an ajax test and on controller return a number and work on js to populate it in text field. Once that is done you only need to work on file read function in controller and return what is in file or summed from file etc.

Answer (score 0):

On click of button make an AJAX call

Sample Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : '@Url.Action("your controller and actions goes here")',
dataType : 'json',
data : {
    //Send file path if it is dynamic
},
success : function (data) {
    //Logic to format and display your text file data
},
error : function (ex) {}
});
```

C# - Server side code:

```
string text;
var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
   text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

send **text** in the JSON format to the client and display it as per your requirment

Refer this link for AJAX implementation http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/jquery-ajax-call-with-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to read line by line from txt file and then I create a stringBuilder and send it to a textare element like this.

```
List<string> linesFromFile= File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string item in linesFromFile)
{
     str.AppendLine(item);
}
ViewBag.RobotsTxt = str;
```